# How get the real path which alias path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, alias

In my rails app,I have add a alias path at apache httpd.conf like this:

```
alias /ckfinder /var/www/html/ckfinder
```

but ,how i can get the real path of '/ckfinder' in model? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I set up ckfinder with rails in detail ?

Comment: I used Apache+Passenger.Firstly you should install php and set up php moudle in Apache.Then write "alias /ckfinder /var/www/html/ckfinder" in the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way for rails to know about apache aliases other than by reading an apache config file and interpreting it yourself.

Remember, rails can be run through other web servers too.

Why can't you just have ckfinder installed in the "public" directory of your rails app so it can always be found relative to the app?